# @Autowired HttpServletRequest inside integration tests

Tags: spring, integration-testing

Finally I have managed to setup the context for some integration test and to test methods that expect @PathVariable or @ModelAttribute. Still, I cannot figure out how can I setup the HTTPServletRequest used inside the controller.

```
MyController {
    @Autowired
private HttpServletRequest request;
}
```

The request never updates while I'm running the test.
I might misunderstand something (as far as I'm new to Spring).
How can I achieve this?
Thanks in advance for the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't have time to fill in the answer: I am using MockHttpServletRequest and Spring 3.1.2.
I have managed to solve it not by using @Autowired, but by getting the request bean from the controler. Something like this:

```
mockRequest = (MockHttpServletRequest) applicationContext.getBean ("request");
```

Hope that this will help someone else ...

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the HttpServletRequest passed in to the controller via a method parameter?
Use @Autowired to connect an instance variable to a Spring context bean.
Maybe you can have a look at MockHttpServletRequest for testing Web controllers.